# JDA - How to get the user ID of the bot itself

Tags: java, discord

I'm making a JDA (Java Discord API) program that needs to check if a message was sent by the bot itself. How can I achieve this? I thought about checking if the user ID of the message sender equals the bot's user ID, but how can I get the user ID of the bot itself in the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the MessageReceivedEvent, you can just check if the sender is a bot by using:
`event.getAuthor.isBot()`.

You can access the user of the bot itself by accessing JDA and calling getSelfUser() as follows with the MessageReceivedEvent in mind:
`event.getJDA().getSelfUser()`

On the SelfUser you can call `SelfUser#getId()` or `SelfUser#getIdLong()` to access the ID.

Example Code

```
public class Listener extends ListenerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    boolean isBot = event.getAuthor().isBot() //Check if the Message Sender is a bot
    
    long id = event.getJDA().getSelfUser().getIdLong() //the bot ID
  }
}
```